# Yamaha MG10XUF inputs 5 - 10 don't produce output on both speakers when I connect my guitar

Tags: mixer

The Yamaha MG10XUF inputs 5 - 10 don't produce output on both speakers when I connect my guitar. Why is that? It seems to be the only analog mixer in the world to do this. The sound comes out of just *one* of the two speakers, every time I connect my AC guitar in the 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 inputs of this mixer.

How can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 2):

This happens with every mixer that uses TRS jacks as the input for stereo channels. Channel 5-10 of this mixer are stereo channels, and you're [connecting a mono source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#Mono_and_stereo_compatibility).

To fix this, either:

- connect the guitar to one of the mono channels 1-4
- or get an adapter with a mono jack on one end, stereo on the other end, and the mono tip connected to both tip and ring. IDK if these are available, you might have to make one yourself.